# how to add a path of a github folder too cdqa pdf_converter? Or extract pdf from a github repository in python

Tags: python, file, pdf, path, extract

I want to convert the pdf files hosted on github, for deployment of my model,rather than  a local folder, but for some reason, it does not seem to extract the pdf from the github folder path

## Download pdf files

```
def download_pdf():
    import os
    import wget
    directory = './data5/pdf/'
    models_url = [
      '',

    ]

    print('\nDownloading PDF files...')

    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)

    for url in models_url:
        wget.download(url=url, out=directory)

download_pdf()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is public thus you can access the page via URL

https://github.com/mohsinmushtaq-arch/pdf-docs/tree/main/docs

To view **using links to view individual docs** it needs to be adapted like this by
**replacing tree with blob** !

```
https://github.com/mohsinmushtaq-arch/pdf-docs/blob/main/docs/FIRE%20AND%20LIFE%20SAFETY%20CODE_Page100.pdf
```

[image]

and **to Download the blob needs to be raw** !!

```
https://github.com/mohsinmushtaq-arch/pdf-docs/raw/main/docs/FIRE%20AND%20LIFE%20SAFETY%20CODE_Page100.pdf
```